# rotate bitmap and size

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I take a picture with camera through intent. After I receive the image, my app has a rotate button. say the image came back width = 900 and height=1200. After I rotate the image, I still want width = 900 and height=1200 as opposed to width = 1200 and height=900. Does anyone know how I might to that?

Here is the code that hasn't worked.

```
Bitmap bmp = readBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), imageUri, sampleScale, options);
float widthScale = 0.9f * deviceDimension[1] / bmp.getWidth();
float heightScale = 0.8f * deviceDimension[0] / bmp.getHeight();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preScale(widthScale, heightScale);
matrix.preRotate(angle);//90x
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

So basically, I want the image to still fit a present dimension on the screen no matter how I orient the image. The present area is, say, 900 by 1200

Answer (score 0):

see if this works??

```
public static Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, float scalingFactor) {
    int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scalingFactor);
    int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scalingFactor);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
}

private float getBitmapScalingFactor(Bitmap bm) {
    // Get display width from device
    int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    // Get margin to use it for calculating to max width of the ImageView
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)this.imageView.getLayoutParams();
    int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
    int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;

    // Calculate the max width of the imageView
    int imageViewWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);

    // Calculate scaling factor and return it
    return ( (float) imageViewWidth / (float) bm.getWidth() );
}
```

Comment: What is make differ from that one? What is special in this ?? and how it is more useful?

Comment: if you want to fit the image to the screen get the scaling factor and then apply that factor to width and height so that image will reduce to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), matrix, true);
```

instead of

```
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```